# How do I get the added value from a drop down list and an input box to show?

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

I am a newbie and I've been wrecking my brain trying to figure out the solution by trying different ways to get the proper results but nothing that I tried so far has worked. I've also tried searching here on stackoverflow and on google. But none of the solutions that were commented so far, solved the issue.

Here's a link to my codes so far: http://pastebin.com/x05nGQ1Y

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
on the input field I can write for an example a product like banana(s) and an apple(s) etc. Then next to it, I have a drop down list which represents the quantity of the specific product that I want. Then at the end I have a onclick button that will show what I have ordered in the form of a ul list. I also have a button with the function of deleting the current list, if I have misspelled something or have set the wrong quantity for a product.

Now here comes the part that I am not able to solve: I am trying to get an input to show the total quantities of all products at the end.

Say I type in banana with the amount of 5 from the drop down list, then I add apples with the amount of 3 and 1 gallon of milk. This means 5 + 3 + 1 = 9 in total products, which I am trying to get to pop up as a result at the end.

Comment: for the record, when asking about html/javascript, please use jsfiddle instead of pastebin: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onclick handler, you need to add code to total up the items in your list.  You haven't provided any information here about how you are storing that data so I am going to assume you only have that data stored in a UL on the page.  In this case, you just need to count the LI elements in your UL and output the result.

It would be easier to help you if you posted your code and a codepen so others could view and modify your code.

EDIT: I see you provided a link.  Here is what I think.  You are storing your data points as LI on the page, instead you should store it in an array of data objects and render the UL from your data array.  Then, you can easily grab the appropriate data points for your calculation.  It is good practice to avoid storing data in the DOM and instead to store it in a separate data structure in the javascript.

For your case, you can keep a counter variable to track of the number of items in the list, and then reset it when the list is cleared.

Comment: I see, I will try that. Thanks for such a fast reply. The way I stored the data, was just through the selection drop down list with values going from 1 to 20 which would mean amount in this case. Not quite sure if that was a clear enough explanation?

By the way, here is my codepen version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpBZGr

To be quite honest, I tried doing what you said but I don't know if I completely got it correctly.

Comment: You were very close.  Here I modified your pen just a little bit and added a few comments: http://codepen.io/McHat/pen/ZpBZpq

Comment: OMG! Sorry for the caps, but thanks a million bunch! I've been trying to figure it out these past couple of days, but I started getting on a tilt form since I wasn't able to spot my mistakes anymore. Hehe, blind from my own codes. Haha. But again, thanks a bunch! May I ask if possible, if you could explain what you did to make it work? So I can maybe try to fully understand it.

Comment: In your code, in the the leggtil function, the line `document.getElementById("varer") = totalv;` was irrelevant and unnecessary so I removed it.  Also in that function you were declaring `var totalv = totalv + tallv;`  The `var` keyword in this context was overwriting your globally scoped totalv variable every time it was executed.  I removed the `var` and now it references your global totalv variable.

After that I just had to add `totalv = 0;` in the tomListe function to reset your global when you clear the list.

Now it works.

Comment: probably you were missing the fact that your totalv variable was being overwritten by the var keyword

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is..

1) Create an input box to display the total

```
<input id="total" value="0" />
```

2) Update the box whenever someone adds an item - Put this is your `leggTil` function somewhere after `antall` is defined.

```
document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').value) + parseInt(antall);
```

This just adds the current item's quantity to the value already in the box.

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oh376pLw/

Also, not related to your question, but your really shouldn't put `<header>` tags in the `<head>` of the document. You also shouldn't put anything between the `<head>` and the `<body>` of the document.

Comment: I see, thanks a bunch for the explanation! I'll try that out too, even if the earlier suggestion actually did solve the case on hand.

By the way, thanks for the heads-up also for where to put my tags.